# Is there a way to avoid Unwanted texts from License Plate?

Tags: deep-learning, ocr, object-detection, google-vision

I am new to License Plate Recognition. I am using Goggle's Vision API(OCR) to extract texts from Images. But this extracts all the texts from the License Plate. For example, consider the image below

[image]

I need to get only the License number **6TRJ244**, but I get all the texts like **california AUF 2012dmv.ca.gov** from the License plate

Can anyone guide me how to avoid other texts and extract only License number? Please do share any other approach for License Plate Recognition I can try that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for that. The License number will be in a specific format for a certain region.
I'm not aware of your country's license plate system, but for the kind of License number shown in the example, it is a number, followed by 3 alphabets and then 3 numbers.

The simplest one I can think of would be `[0-9][A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`
There can be some other formats also, and you can write regex for each. The additional info on the license plate is not of that kind that'd result in any false detection.

For testing your regex you can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DlkzEC/7)
I tested your example and these were the results.
[image]